# Blazor InvokeAsync no longer working after page reload

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have a Blazor page (server-side) that uses an async call to Azure Service Bus to get some data and print the result to the page. Everything works fine at first. However, if the user reloads the page, the page does not get re-rendered as intended.

Debugging with breakpoints shows that the model *is* updated, and the call to `StateHasChanged` *is* executed after the page reload; it just simply doesn't do anything. I was under the impression that `InvokeAsync` is supposed to always use the UI thread, but that doesn't seem to be the case after a page reload.

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  // On page load. Service bus watcher is hooked up here
  await serviceBusHandler.WatchQueue("servicebus-queue", MessageHandler, async _ => await Task.CompletedTask);
}

// "request" method; calls a Service Bus method get a new value for our model
private async Task SaveAndGetAmount()
{
  IsLoading = true;

  // creation of Service Bus message omitted
  // post to "servicebus-queue" with message here
}

private async Task MessageHandler(ProcessSessionMessageEventArgs args)
{
  var result = ... // parsing of "args" message omitted

  await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message); // mark Azure Functions message received
  
  await InvokeAsync(() =>
  {
    IsLoading = false;
    Model.Amount = result.Amount; // update page model here
    StateHasChanged(); // indicate to UI that the model has changed, and the page must re-render
  });
```

Additionally, I added a watch to the `Model.Amount` property and it's exhibiting some weird behavior. If it's set to say 23 on initial page load, the watch will always show 23 on my breakpoint in the `SaveAndGetAmount` method, as if it's never being updated by the `MessageHandler` method.

Comment: InvokeAsync isn't broken. The problem is somewhere else. Best is a [mre] but at least show how MessageHandler is called. Any `async void`  methods in the picture?

Comment: Thanks; I added the call to MessageHandler. It's part of a Service Bus hookup.

Comment: There were a couple `async void` methods someone added but I don't think they are directly related to this code. When I replaced them with `async Task` it broke my loading spinner (the `IsLoading` variable in my question), annoyingly.

Comment: you should call WatchQueue on each OnAfterRenderAsync, just when firstRender is true. Henk Holterman is right. The problem is somewhere else. The code you have posted works

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; `WatchQueue` *does* get called on each `OnAfterRenderAsync`; we ignore `firstRender`.

Comment: Why do you ignore firstRender?  Is serviceBusHandler a Singleton or Scoped or ...?  You leave a lot of guesswork on the table.  And that loading spinner isn't above suspicion either.

Comment: `serviceBusHandler` is scoped (if it were scoped, the whole site breaks) and injected on the .razor file, but I don't think it's particularly relevant, as it's been working fine. The loading spinner thing makes me think that this is an issue with UI threading.

Comment: If you `reload` a page, you create it, you do not re-render it. Got it. Do you still support this term. And if you reload, you do not call the StateHasChanged method. It is automatically called. Do you understand what the OnAfterRenderAsync does.

Comment: @Andrew: read your last comment again. Is it Scoped or not?

Comment: Oops, it's scoped, not singleton. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WatchQueue does get called on each OnAfterRenderAsync; we ignore firstRender

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  // On page load. Service bus watcher is hooked up here
  await serviceBusHandler.WatchQueue("servicebus-queue", MessageHandler, async _ => await Task.CompletedTask);
}
```

Just a guess here but this means every (Re)Render adds a messagehandler. That is wrong but goes unnoticed as long as you're on the same instance of the page.

After a reload your messages are still handled on the old (defunct) page. That is what I think you see happening in the debugger.

If I'm right the solution is two-fold:

```
@implements IDisposable

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)  // only once per page
  {
    // On page load. Service bus watcher is hooked up here
    await serviceBusHandler.WatchQueue("servicebus-queue", MessageHandler, async _ => await Task.CompletedTask);
  }
}

public void Dispose()
{
  // somehow undo the WatchQueue 
}
```

If you can't unhook that handler then it's at the wrong place.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I guess we were creating too many of those handlers on page load.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are hooking up the `serviceBusHandler` in `OnAfterRenderAsync` rather than in `OnInitialisedAsync`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The page doesn't work if we do that. I get an error like "... When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method."

Comment: @Andrew.  No problem, if you're using JSInterop then your stuck with `OnAfterRender` and `firstRender`.